# Can you tell me where this Mega Bloks part is from?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I found this part and was wondering what set it's from, thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more angles and confirm 100% it's Mega Bloks please.

Comment: Can't swear its mega Bloks but it as a number like others mega Bloks I own AM02077 and fits them

Comment: The additional pictures are helpful, thank you.  Mega Bloks are often very difficult to ID because of the limited resources available.  We'll do our best ;)

Comment: @ Mathieu.  You said It has a number like other MBs you own. Please give pictures of a few blocks that share this number, so we can cross reference their sets.  Also give pictures of how this piece connects to other MB pieces.  I see a box of parts in the background.  Did this piece come together with those in the box of parts?  If so, dump the box and give up a snap shot of the pieces.  THX,

Comment: well it is surely mega becuase its size

Comment: it also looks like a frame part at the start of a car you know the decration pece